# Component TSomething can't be registered by package something_design.bpl because it has already been registered by package something_design.bpl.?

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe, design-time

One of the dread errors with design-time packages in Delphi, which means packages that register install new components onto your Palette, is this error:

> Component TSomething can't be registered by package something_design.bpl 
>   because it has  already been registered by package something_design.bpl.?

I already know this much:

1. If you had two copies of the BPL and you loaded one, but another package that depends on the BPL tries to load another, and it tries to load a second copy, you get this error.
2. Sometimes, there are weird things about implicit imports that require you to fix the implicit import warnings, clean all your artifacts up (dcu,dcp etc) and try again, and this goes away.

However, in the case that NEITHER of the above is fixing the problem, how do you fix the problem?

It seems to me, that there is only one copy of this BPL on my hard drive, and the path points to it, and somehow, a package is doing a "stealthy" background load of the package, before the IDE can see it, and then the IDE itself tries to load a package which has gotten loaded into the memory of the IDE using the Win32 call [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the second load which is the IDE trying to load this package, is causing a failure.

I'm looking for:

A. How to figure out what is wrong, and how to fix it.

B. Ways to avoid this (defensive practices or tools to scan your packages or your delphi IDE configuration.)

C. Workarounds. For example, I have found that launching Delphi ide (bds.exe) with the `-np` parameter, then loading my project later, not at initial IDE startup time, sometimes works around the problem by delaying project/form opens until a later time, when the Delphi IDE seems more stable.

Comment: You might try to reorder the package list inside the registry. For this you have to export the registry key, delete it, reorder the .reg file and reimport it.

Comment: Uwe you are on to something.  It definitely helps to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, are you working in XE?
I struggled with this after I made a component to replace the calendar earlier this year. I'm still not exactly sure what fixed it. But I believe the error has to do with the paths. Ensure it's not included twice by being visible to 2 path definitions.

If it's being used, you should be able to see what packages are included.

Hope you can make sense out of this, I'm still wondering what I did back then.

Answer (score 0):

With all other aspects being correct (paths, # of copies, etc)...I experience this problem when my IDE package is dependent on other (3rd party) packages already installed into the IDE.  The KEY is to get the other package loaded so that when you build your package, it recognizes the proper "Requires" and launches the dialog for you to agree to add it.  You can load the other package by adding an empty new project alongside your package in the Project Manager and throwing some of the 3rd party controls onto a form.  Now when you compile your package, it should see the other package and include it in the Requires list.

I suppose you could add the ForceDemandLoadState(dlDisable) into the 3rd party package, but who would want to?